# how to search on twitter using Tweetinvi with specific keywords. like who is the winner of SA vs SLR match

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

I have search on this link "https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search" but it does not contains very good documentation

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

The Tweetinvi documentation regarding searches can be found at https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Searches#tweet-searches.

As a simple example you can search with the following code :

```
var matchingTweets = Search.SearchTweets("tweetinvi");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchParameter = new SearchTweetsParameters("#Benz")
    {
        //GeoCode = new GeoCode(-122.398720, 37.781157, 1, DistanceMeasure.Miles),
        Lang = LanguageFilter.English,
        //SearchType = SearchResultType.Popular,
        //MaximumNumberOfResults = 100,
        Until = new DateTime(2018, 03, 07),
        //SinceId = 399616835892781056,
        //MaxId = 405001488843284480,
        Filters = TweetSearchFilters.Images
    };

 var tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchParameter);
```

Comment: How would that find out who the winner of "SA vs SLR" was?